# php SQL select query not working

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

Im trying to query my db of of MySQL on localhost. All i want to do is to see if the $name of a user is equal to any of the values from the 'userName' column in my db . If yes to say yes else no .

My code :

```
try 
    {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=datab", $username, $pass);
        // set the PDO error mode to exception
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        //echo "Connected successfully"; 
            $sql = 'SELECT passWord FROM datab WHERE userName = '$name''; 

            $res = $conn->query($sql)
            if($res>0)
            {
                echo "user found";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "not in db";
            }

    }
```

Comment: Look at the quotes at your `$sql` declaration

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT passWord FROM datab WHERE userName = '$name'";`

Comment: It should be $sql = "SELECT passWord FROM datab WHERE userName = '$name'";

Comment: thanks for that ! but it didnt solve my prob, neither echo statements are being displayed

Comment: @MakDo Add error reporting at the top of your file(s): `<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ?>` And tell us if you get any

Comment: @Rizier123 didnt know i can do that ! thanks ! but even then no errors are being displayed !

Answer (score 2):

If you're using PDO, then it's also smart to use prepared statements so you avoid potential injections or unwanted errors.

Refer to the code:

```
try 
{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=datab", $username, $pass);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    //echo "Connected successfully"; 

    $sql = 'SELECT passWord FROM datab WHERE userName = :name'; 

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); // Prepare

    $stmt->bindValue(':name', $name);

    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

    if(count($result))
    {
        echo 'User found';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'User not found';
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: neither echo statements are being displyed ! thats my initial problem !

Comment: Well, that just means we ended up in an exception that I didn't catch in my code. Refer to the edit please.

Comment: the code stops before the line $stmt ->execute() ;

Answer (score 0):

i got it !! the error was that the dbname = datab but when writing the select clause it should have been

```
 $sql = 'SELECT passWord FROM datab_a WHERE userName = :name';
```

since you access the table name datab_a not the database name datab !
Thanks anyways